# Microsoft Graph WebHook not getting Notifcation

Tags: web, graph, push-notification

We have active subscriptions created with a GraphWebHook and everything has been running fine for last 4 months. Suddenly today we do not receive any notification from Microsoft o365 server. What could be the problem and how can we trace the issue. Fiddler shows nothing is sent to out WebHook when we change in outlook.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Anamika

Comment: Generic questions hardly receive a good answer. Please, explain your problem and your attempts to fix it as clearly as possible. The more detailed the better.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem.  One event was signaled but nothing else. Get /subscriptions shows active subscriptions but none are being received.